# How to correctly use Android View Binding in DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-viewbinding

What is correct way of using Android View Binding in DialogFragment()?

Official documentation mentions only Activity and Fragment:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))` instead. And use `binding.root` to set the builder view.

Also, as Google suggests, it's best practice to set the `binding` instance to null at `onDestroyView()` when using fragments:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments

Example:

```
class ExampleDialog : DialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: DialogExampleBinding? = null
    // This property is only valid between onCreateDialog and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        _binding = DialogExampleBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
            .setView(binding.root)
            .create()
    }
    
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is recommended to prevent crashes but what happens if binding is used after it is set to null? I think it will crash, which means `private val binding get() = _binding!!` makes no sense at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: You shouldn't use the view once it reaches the onDestroyView life cycle.

Comment: Also, it is a better pratice to use your binding as a local variable. No need to override onDestroyView in this case ! :)

Comment: This will crash sometimes as @Mehmed said.

Comment: Is `onDestroyView` necessary for _binding?

Comment: use lateinit for global, and without need of global variable, just use locally inside onviewcreated

Comment: What should I do in case I use FragmentViewBindingDelegate in this case of DialogFragment?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, yes. When a fragment recreates a view, it's `_binding` receives a new value. To detect where a view is destroyed, check `_binding == null` (for instance, after long loading operations).