# ViewBinding in a Dialogfragment using a customview

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-viewbinding

I have a question about using `viewBinding` in a dialog fragment, that uses a custom view. Is there a standard way of doing this?

My code that uses `findViewById()` for the dialog fragment but I would like to use viewbinding as that is standard across the rest of my project.

```
class WifiHandlerDialogFragment(private val wifiErrorType: Int): DialogFragment() {

private var _binding: DialogWifiHandlerBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

    _binding = DialogWifiHandlerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

    val dialog = activity?.let {
        Dialog(it)
    }

    if(dialog != null) {
        dialog.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_wifi_handler)
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        val positiveButton = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.positive_button) // really want to change this to use binding
        val closeButton = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.close_button) // really want to change this to use binding
        val dialogMessage = dialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_message)

        positiveButton.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
        }
        closeButton.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }

        dialogMessage.text = when (wifiErrorType) {
            1 ->  getString(R.string.connection_dialog_op1)
            2 -> getString(R.string.connection_dialog_op2)
            3 -> getString(R.string.connection_dialog_op3)
            else -> getString(R.string.error)
        }

    }

    return dialog!!
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
}
```

I was trying to use `binding.closebutton` in the `onCreateDialog()` function but that us not working (I assume due to fragment lifecycle).

I have looked at these questions:

[How to correctly use Android View Binding in DialogFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205151/how-to-correctly-use-android-view-binding-in-dialogfragment)

[Android DialogFragment onViewCreated not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594992/android-dialogfragment-onviewcreated-not-called)

But still haven't worked out what is the best way to achieve this (also my first time using `viewbinding` coming from kotlin synthetics).

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. Simply wasn't setting content view to `binding.root`. Works fine now. https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/exploring-view-binding-in-activities-fragments-dialogs-and-recyclerview-adapters-789f84b31a2a

```
class WifiHandlerDialogFragment(private val wifiErrorType: Int): DialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: DialogWifiHandlerBinding? = null
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        _binding = DialogWifiHandlerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

        val dialog = activity?.let {
            Dialog(it)
        }

        if(dialog != null) {
            dialog.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            dialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN)
            dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            dialog.setContentView(binding.root)

            binding.positiveButton.setOnClickListener {
                startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
            }
            binding.closeButton.setOnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            }

            binding.dialogMessage.text = when (wifiErrorType) {
                1 ->  getString(R.string.connection_dialog_op1)
                2 -> getString(R.string.connection_dialog_op2)
                3 -> getString(R.string.connection_dialog_op3)
                else -> getString(R.string.error)
            }

        }
        return dialog!!
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use `binding.root`?